# Why does length of objects seem different in different configurations of object and observer?

Tags: optics, everyday-life, lenses

Today, I had gone to my friend’s garden. There was a dried water well in his garden. We got curious that know how much its depth is. First, we stood on top of the well and estimated its depth.
[image]
We estimated that the depth is approximately $6\mathrm m$.
Then we found a wooden rod and used it for measuring the depth.
[image]
When we put the rod on the ground, before measuring it by meter, we said “Oh, this cannot be $6\mathrm m$. Maybe $4$”
[image]
My friend said that in vertical mood, we feel it is lengthier than horizontal because we fear of height. I didn’t accept and gave another example that there was no height and we feel different length too. I said if we look at inside a horizontal pipe, we feel it is lengthier than when we look at it from outside.
[image]
[image]
Finally, none of us got satisfied. (I am not familiar with optics and couldn’t explain my opinion)

---

I think probably there is something related to optics and mechanism of our eyes and maybe temperature gradient of the air. But, I don’t know anymore.

Is my guess (or my friend’s!) correct? And why?

(If it helps) Figure below shows another situation that we get wrong in estimation.
[image]

Comment: Don't you think this might be a matter of being skilled in those kinds of estimates and may have nothing to do with Physics?

Comment: @QuantumBrick Maybe, I don't know.

Comment: There is no physical justification for what you're asking. Air gradient doesn't play any part in such configurations, only if you were measuring something several hundreds of metres long. Eye structure would deform your vision in all directions, not only vertical. I'm positive this is just an impression of someone that's not used to estimating heights. As I climber I'm always in need of estimating the length of ropes and mountains and I feel my height estimates are pretty precise... Probably because, after many years, I learned to do it and don't fear heights (so I'm not tricked by fear).

Comment: @QuantumBrick Your idea is correct, but here I don't want to compare estimation skill of two persons. I am talking about estimation of **same person** in different configurations.

Comment: My answer still applies: it's a matter of practise, not physics. If you practise you'll see estimating length in any configurations is the same thing...

Comment: It is well known that people are—without extensive training,—*horrible* at estimating vertical distances. Even know the problem doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is unrelated to physics, but is part of a brand called psychophysics, that is, the study of perception. In the visual psychophysics branch of depth perception, you are interested in finding not only what depth information reaches your eye, but how and if all this information is used by your brain to estimate depth. Not all optic information is there to compute depth, the computational problem is often ill defined, and the brain perform several tricks to improve the estimate based on previous experience. The asymmetry up-down versus left-right is known in psychophysics, and also the near (up to about an arm's length) versus far, is known and not uncommon in various areas of visual psychophysics. See for instance   http://link.springer.com/article/10.3758%2FBF03334820